# Why does ColdFusion think that the value "7+" is a valid integer value, and how I can validate that it is not?

Tags: forms, validation, coldfusion, textinput

I have a form for users to input quantities. The form has client-side validation to ensure that the value is an integer and within a given range. The action page has server-side validation to ensure that the value is an integer and greater than zero.

However, one type of value gets through the validation and is causing my INSERT/UPDATE queries to throw exceptions. That value is an integer with a plus-sign - ie "7+" or "12+".

When such a value is entered, the ColdFusion-generated JavaScript validation throws a JavaScript error:

```
_CF_checkformAddToCart = function(_CF_this)
{
    //reset on submit
    _CF_error_exists = false;
    _CF_error_messages = new Array();
    _CF_error_fields = new Object();
    _CF_FirstErrorField = null;

    //form element itemQuantity 'INTEGER' validation checks
    if (!_CF_checkinteger(_CF_this['itemQuantity'].value, false))
    {
        _CF_onError(_CF_this, "itemQuantity", _CF_this['itemQuantity'].value, "Error on itemQuantity, please enter an integer value for quantity that is not greater than 500");
        _CF_error_exists = true;
    }

    //form element itemQuantity 'RANGE' validation checks
    if  (!_CF_checkrange(_CF_this['itemQuantity'].value, 0.0,500.0, false))
    {
        _CF_onError(_CF_this, "itemQuantity", _CF_this['itemQuantity'].value, "Error on itemQuantity, please enter an integer value for quantity that is not greater than 500");
        _CF_error_exists = true;
    }
}
```

Once I cancel out of the error popup, it goes to the action page, where I [try to] validate the value like so:

```
<cfif IsValid("integer", form.itemQuantity) AND form.itemQuantity GT 0>
    <cfquery>
        INSERT ....
```

However, if try this...

```
<cfset x = Int("7+") />
```

...ColdFusion throws an error.

Is it an integer or not ColdFusion???

How can get around this and validate my form input correctly?

Comment: time to report the JS validation bug?  JS upgrade for cfform client side validation is long overdue.

Comment: Henry, it's a CF error not a JS error.  Note the isValid() call claims "7+" is an integer when it's clearly not.  That said, it's def a *CF* bug!

Answer (score 4):

`isNumeric(form.itemQuantity)` will return false for "7+", so to fully validate your input as an int, you can do this

```
<cfif isNumeric(form.itemQuantity) and IsValid("integer", form.itemQuantity) AND form.itemQuantity GT 0>
```

Comment: No, but all integers are numeric

Comment: Yes, but the requirement is that it gets validated *as an integer*, which isNumeric() won't achieve.  isNumeric() will return true for 3.14, which does not fulfil the requirement that the value is an integer.  What one COULD do is to do
isNumeric(form.itemQuantity) && isValid("integer", form.itemQuantity)
but simply isNumeric() by itself is not a valid suggestion for this question.

Comment: You are correct. I've edited my answer to fully validate as numeric and as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the weird and wonderful nature of ColdFusion being typeless. It doesn't know what type of data you are working with and it tries to guess.

Its evaluating that 7+ is a valid. The validation built into ColdFusion makes a lot of assumptions and guesses.

My advise would be to not use it and to write your own validation routines that can be enhanced to do whatever you require.

For example

A user enters

2,075

Is this valid or invalid. Well if you have your own validation you can decide, you can say sure this is an integer and remote the , or you can say no they can't do that.

It's a small investment upfront that will pay off in the long run.

Comment: I agree.  ColdFusion gets very confused when it comes to types.  For example, it is incredibly inconsistent with something like "1,2":

- IsValid("integer", "1,2") // YES
- IsNumeric("1,2") // NO
- Passing in "1,2" to a function that only accepts numeric arguments (e.g. <cfargument name="id" type="numeric" required="true" />) will be allowed.

How bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can use LSParseNumber() to convert it to valid integer. So, now I'm testing for a valid integer, then resetting it using LSParseNumber() before attempting any database inserts:

```
<cfset addItemQty = 0 />

<cfif IsValid("integer", Trim(form.itemQuantity))>
    <cfset addItemQty = LSParseNumber(Trim(form.itemQuantity)) />
</cfif>
```

I guess I'll have to re-engineer the front-end client-side validation to properly validate.

Comment: Are you using cfqueryparam? If so, did it allow the value?